# tastypie accessing data from non pk field

Tags: python, django, web-services, resources, tastypie

I tried this example from [Tastypie Cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls).

By adding this code to access user Resource from the username rather than the id.

```
 #myapp/api/resources.py
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<username>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

this is my URL file,

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(userResource())
```

this is all the available URLs,

```
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/set/(?P<pk_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']
```

What I am looking for instead of calling this url

http://myDomain.com:8000/api/v1/users/1/?format=json

I want to call based on the username

http://myDomain.com:8000/api/v1/users/myUserName/?format=json

Comment: the question is what wrong in my code to access my resource by username not by the id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of tastypie are you using? 0.9.11 uses `override_urls` while 0.9.12 (beta) introduced `prepend_urls` and the cookbook is different for the two version. Chances are you are still using 0.9.11.

See:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls

Comment: i thought latest version 0.9.11 as it mentioned in pip tool,thanks dude